# NullReferenceException occurs in DropDownListFor , ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, nullreferenceexception, html.dropdownlistfor

I am new to ASP.NET MVC.I am working with a sample Project using Individual User Accounts. I created a new Area in my project folder and it contains UserManagement Folder. It contains a file named UserManagementMethods.cs which has following code :

```
namespace Library.Areas.UserManagement
{
    public  class UserManagementMethods
    {
            public  IEnumerable<string> GetGenderList()
            {
            List<string> GenderGroup =  new List<string>
                                                        {
                                                            "Male",
                                                            "Female",
                                                            "Not in the Above",
                                                        };
            return GenderGroup;

            }

            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectedGenderItem(IEnumerable<string> elements)
            {

                foreach (var element in elements)
                {
                    selectList.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = element,
                        Text = element
                    });
                }

                return selectList;
            }

    }
}
```

In the AccountController, I created a UserManagementMethods object, userManagement :

```
 using Library.Areas.UserManagement;
 ........
 ........
 UserManagementMethods userManagement = new UserManagementMethods();
```

Then in the Register() in the AccountController, I called UserManagementMethods methods

```
var genderList   = userManagement.GetGenderList();
var model = new RegisterViewModel();
model.GenderList = userManagement.GetSelectedGenderItem(genderList);
return View();
```

I created a DropDownList in Register.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
   <div class="col-md-8">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, Model.GenderList, "Select An  Option", new { @class = "form-control" })
   </div>
</div>
```

When I run the project and navigate to `/Account/Register`, **NullReferenceException** occurs near to DropDownListFor Field.

`/Account/Register`

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 49: @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender, new { @class= "col-md-4 control-label"})<
Line 50:   <div class="col-md-8"> 
Line 51:       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, Model.GenderList, "Select An  Option", new { @class = "form-control" })
Line 52:   </div> 
Line 53:</div>
```

Comment: Because you do not return the model to the view so its `null` in the view - `return View(model);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't sending the model to the view.

```
return View();
```

should be

```
return View(model);
```